# Erro: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: html, node.js, cross-domain

[AJUDA] Não estou conseguindo acessar o JSON do meu servidor;
Estou utilizando este código para fazer o acesso,
quando utilizo o urlSrt, ele me retorna normalmente, (é um site que recebe um cep e retorna um json com as informações);
Mas quando tento isso na minha api não funcionada.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
console.log("Página carregada");
$("#descricao").focusout(() =>{
const cep = $("#descricao").val();

const urlStr = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/";
const urlStr2 = "ip" + ":3000/categorias/1";

$.ajax({
url: urlStr2,
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
crossDomain : true,
success: (data) => {
console.log(data);
},
error: ((error) => {
console.log(error);
})
})
});
})´´´
```

Verifiquei uns tutoriais que diziam para liberar a permissão , mas mesmo assim não funcionou.;

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
next();
})´´´
```

Em fim, estou sem mais ideias

Comment: Esta tentando acessar por uma aplicação front end ? Se tiver acesso ao servidor back end, realize as edições de cors no back, caso não possua será necessário um configuração de proxy em seu front

Comment: Exatamente, eu até tenho acesso ao servidor, e nele foi que coloquei o res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*"); mas mesmo assim ele continua com o erro.
Como faria essa configuração de proxy?

Comment: Tentou utilizar `dataType: "jsonp"` ou `$.support.cors = true;` ?